# Use HTML Form's Input Fields with Multiple Forms

Tags: html

Im attempting to make code that provides the user with the option to add their car's VIN and mileage or give them the option to update their car's VIN and mileage. I want to make it clean by having two separate buttons, but using the same input fields with the POST request parameters.

### Add Car Form

```html
<!-- Form for Adding VIN -->
<form class="p-3 mt-3" onsubmit="return validateInput()" action="Mileage.php" method="post">
    <!-- Direct User to Fillout Accordingly -->
    <h6 style="margin-top: 25px; color: #000000; font-size: 25px;">Enter Your Information</h6>

    <div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;" class="push">
        <!-- VIN Input Field -->
        <div class="mt-3" style="padding-right: 25px;">
            <input type="text" name="vehicle" id="vehicle" placeholder="Vehicle ID #" required>
        </div>

        <!-- Mileage Input Field -->
        <div class="mt-3">
            <input type="text" name="mileage" id="mileage" placeholder="Mileage (Ex: 10000)" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Add VIN & Mileage Button -->
    <button class="btn mt-4" type="submit">Add Car</button>
</form>
```

### Update Car Form

```
<!-- Form for Updating VIN -->
<form class="p-3 mt-3" action="Update.php" method="post">
    <button class="btn mt-4" type="submit">Update Car</button>
</form>
```

I want to use the input fields from the Add Car Form with the Update Car Form's POST request.

Comment: Well you can easily copy and paste the html. Are you actually asking how to pre-populate those fields in the "update" form with the existing values from your database, perhaps? Otherwise it's not very clear exactly what the issue/question is. See also [ask]

Comment: @ADyson I am trying to make it so that theres only one set of input boxes on the web application. I want to make the most of the space and having four sets of input boxes isnt visually appealing IMO. Therefore, I want to use the Add Car Form's input fields for the Update Car's POST parameters as well.

Comment: You can make even more of the space if you replace the two submit buttons by just one "Save" button. Adding and updating seem to do the same in your interface.

Comment: KiKO's suggestion is one option, although when editing you also need to submit something to uniquely identify the existing record to be updated

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Ahh I guess context is important. I am making an application that is specifically vulnerable to a UNION injection attack, and just the the sake of application I am making a separate update function to make the code vulnerable. Which will display the results of a UNION Select statement within the mileage field and display on the user's page.

Comment: Or, why not just only show each of the forms when the user actually asks for that functionality  rather than having it all on the page at once. The user can click to select the task they want to do (add or update) and then be shown the appropriate form

Comment: That "Save" button doesn't have to have the same title. So, when there's no data yet it could be "Add Car", but when there is data it could be changed to "Update Car".

Comment: @ADyson I am using the user's $_SESSION['username'] variable as a unique identifier to pull VINs and mileage's associated with the user.

Comment: OK, so if this is just a demo application to show how injection attacks work then why are you spending time worrying about the user experience at all? Just slap some forms on there and get on with it

Comment: @ADyson LOL, I suppose you're right. Its for a capstone project to complete my degree so I thought I would go out with something I can be proud of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give the 2 buttons names, and check which button has been clicked in PHP code.

Also, you don't have to use 2 forms. Just use one form and put both buttons inside it. In that form, for the action attribute, put the PHP file's name. Like below.

```
<form action="your_php_file_name.php" methord="post">
  //HTML code for the form
<button name="add_data_button_name" type="submit">ADD</button>
<button name="update_data_button_name" type="submit">UPDATE</button>
</form>
```

Write both scenarios in the same PHP file and use the below format to check which button has been clicked.

```
<?php
//Databse Conection

if(isset($_POST['add_data_button_name'])) {
// Code to handle adding new data

} elseif(isset($_POST['update_data_button_name'])) {
// Code to handle updating existing data

}
```

Hope you find this useful.